# How to perform operations on n number of strings and than print them in C++?

Tags: c++, function, invoke

I have a program where a number of n C++ strings are entered. I want to enter them with a for loop and than to print the result of the function int operate(string t) for each of them on a new line? In other words, can I invoke the function operate(), after I have entered the strings (for each of them)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int n,counter=0;
int operate (string t)
{
    int st=t.find_first_of('E');
    for(st; st<t.length(); st++)
    {
        if(t[st]=='.')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
string k;
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>k;
        operate(k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to [debug it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) then.

Comment: What do you mean _returns nothing_? You never even take the return value from your function?

Comment: It returns . But You did not stored the return value. Assign the return value to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

It returns but you did not stored the return value.

Print the return value like

```
cout<<operate(k);
```

Else assign the return value to another variable.
The returned value is stored in another variable.

```
int temp;
temp = operate(k);
court<<temp;
```